# Need an extension to view the office documents in chrome

Tags: chrome

I am using alfresco 4.2e. In alfresco share, you can preview the docs and ppts and other office documents with the built in previewer. Sometime for large file (4 or 5 MB) the preview  will take time to load. Alfresco share has a view in browser option.

Previously I installed [Chrome Office Viewer Beta](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-office-viewer-beta/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj?hl=en) and I am able to preview the files quickly. Unfortunately I uninstalled the extension and now I am unable to install it again. I am getting  `Package is invalid could not unzip extension`.

I need an extension just like [Chrome Office Viewer Beta](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-office-viewer-beta/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj?hl=en) so that I can preview office files on chrome.

I checked in Chrome Store and as far as I could  rest of them are installing as app in chrome rather than an extension like chrome office viewer. This extension should be able to display files stored in local system (alfresco repository). (Chrome office viewer was able to preview the files)

I am using:

Windows 7 64 bit

Chrome version: 35.0.1916.114 m

Comment: The error part is not really on topic here - you could probably get help over at [Webapps.se](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or via whatever support the author offers.

Comment: ([Meta discussion](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/847/60) about this question.)

Comment: Do you mean the default preview feature built in Alfresco Share is not enough for you? Do you want to preview BEFORE downloading or BEFORE downloading?

Comment: Yes the preview is taking some time to load bigger files. I need to view the file in browser not to download

Answer (score 3):

[Docs PDF/Powerpoint Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/docs-pdfpowerpoint-viewer/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn?hl=en) should fill you needs. Despite it's atrociously poor naming 
it supports a *lot* more formats; here's the configuration screen:
[[image]]

It works pretty well and I've never run into any significant issues with it. You do have to view files in *raw* mode to properly preview github - and then they show up real nice and just like in real Word:
[image]

Comment: Also, being a webapp rather than an extension, it should more or less just work, potential for slightly non standard layout aside.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I tried it before. It is not working like chrome office viewer. I am accessing files in my local system in my application and it shows  `Sorry, we were unable to find the document at the original source. Verify that the document still exists.` But chrome office viewer is able to preview my files

Comment: Oh yes this will not work in the local filesystem that is true.